# How to create an overloaded version of the function for SmtpException?

Tags: c#

I have the following method to send an email and method to wrap an exception:

```
public void SendEmail(SendEmailRequest emailRequest)
{
    ...
    catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException e)
    {
        var failedRecipients = e.InnerExceptions.Select(x => x.FailedRecipient);
        LogAndReThrowWithValidMessage(e, EmailsLocalization.EmailDeliveryFailed, emailRequest.Subject, serverSettings, failedRecipients);
    }
    catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException e)
    {
        LogAndReThrowWithValidMessage(e, EmailsLocalization.EmailDeliveryFailed, emailRequest.Subject, serverSettings, new[] { e.FailedRecipient });
    }
    catch (SmtpException e)
    {
        LogAndReThrowWithValidMessage(e, EmailsLocalization.EmailSendFailedInvalidSettings, emailRequest.Subject, serverSettings);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         LogAndReThrowWithValidMessage(e, EmailsLocalization.EmailSendFailedGeneralIssues, emailRequest.Subject, serverSettings);
    }
    ...
}

private static void LogAndReThrowWithValidMessage(Exception e, string message, string logSubject, SmtpServerSettings logSettings, IEnumerable<string> failedRecipients = null)
{
    _logger.ErrorException(e,
        "Exception while trying to send message with subject '{0}' using SMTP server {1}:{2}",
         logSubject,
         logSettings.SmtpServerName,
         logSettings.SmtpPort);

    var sendingFailedException = new EmailSendingFailedException(message, e);
    var smtpException = e as SmtpException;
    if (smtpException != null)
    {
        var isGmailServerName = logSettings.SmtpServerName.Contains("gmail.com");
        if (isGmailServerName && smtpException.InnerException.Message.Contains("net_io_connectionclosed"))
        {
            sendingFailedException = new EmailSendingFailedException(EmailsLocalization.EmailSendFailedWrongPortNumber, e);
        }

        // Wrapping authentication exceptions
        if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MustIssueStartTlsFirst || 
            smtpException.Message.Contains("AUTH"))
        {
            sendingFailedException = isGmailServerName ? 
                    new EmailSendingFailedException(EmailsLocalization.EmailSendFailedAuthenticationProblemForGmail, e) : 
                    new EmailSendingFailedException(EmailsLocalization.EmailSendFailedAuthenticationProblem, e);
        }

        // According to Yahoo's spam policy
        if (smtpException.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxNameNotAllowed)
        {
            sendingFailedException = new EmailSendingFailedException(EmailsLocalization.EmailSendFailedWrongFromAddress, e);
        }
    }

    if (failedRecipients != null)
    {
        sendingFailedException.FailedRecipients = failedRecipients;
    }

    throw sendingFailedException;
}
```

How to create an overloaded version of the function for `SmtpException` that will implement this logic and then call the original method to log ant wrap. Also, now my refined message is missing in logs, how to fix that?

Comment: could you just design a class inheriting from `SmtpException`? then put the code to send it at the end of the constructor so when create it, it sends a copy?

Comment: Does it really need to be overloaded? This will be difficult, as an `SmtpException` is also an `Exception` and thus can fulfill the contract for either method. Why not just name it differently? i.e. `LogAndReThrowSmtpException`, then have that method call `LogAndReThrowWithValidMessage` after completing its work.

Comment: Nice idea. But what do you mean by " thus can fulfill the contract for either method."?